# CATransition with UINavigationController: keyboard disappears

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, catransition

I'm doing a custom animation in UINavigationController that allows to hide the tabbar in the first view.

It starts from a sort of text view with the virtual keyboard and displays a UITableViewController:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.25f;
transition.type =  kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
[navigationController pushViewController:preferencesViewController animated:NO];
```

But my problem is that the keyboard disappears instantly just before starting the transition.

I would like to do a push transition that moves the keyboard together with the first view.

Is this possible without having to do a screenshot of the first view?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found how to do it, I have this instead of `[window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];`:

```
for (UIWindow *someWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    if (![someWindow respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [someWindow screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        [someWindow.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
```

Now I'm trying to get working the opposite (return to the first view). I want to have the keyboard translating together with the first view. But instead it only appears after the view has finished it's translation.

Perhaps I have to obtain the view of the keyboard before applying the animation?

EDIT: I got it working, I changed my tactic:
I make the transition between the rootviewcontroller and the navigationcontroller.
I disallow the textfield to resign and I hide the keyboard view during the transition.